# Contolling an LCD display in VHDL on Nexys A7 100T

Tags: vhdl, hdl, lcd

I'm looking to control an external display where the pins are connected to the ports JA and JB on the Nexys A7 100T, I've configured the state machine below according to the instructions in the datasheet but nothing is being displayed. Since this is the first time I'm controlling a display through VHDL, I suspect that either the display is not working or something is not being initialized in the correct manner.

```
 --- Initialization and Data transfer of LCD display---
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity LCD is
    generic(
        display_lines  :      std_logic  := '0'; --Amount of displaylines: (0 = 1-line, 1 = 2-lines) 
        font_type      :      std_logic  := '0'; -- Font type: (0 = 5x8 font, 1 = 5x11 font but only available for 1 line mode) 
        display_on     :      std_logic  := '1'; -- Diplay ON/OFF: (0 = OFF, 1 = ON)
        display_off    :      std_logic  := '0';
        cursor         :      std_logic  := '0'; -- Cursor ON/OFF: (0 = OFF, 1 = ON)
        blink          :      std_logic  := '0'; -- Blink ON/OFF:  (0 = OFF, 1 = ON)
        I_D            :      std_logic  := '1'; -- Increment/Decrement (0 = Decrement(move left), 1 = Increment(Move right))
        shift          :      std_logic  := '1'; -- Shift of display( 0 = Shift not perfomed, 1 = shift done according to I/D)
        LCD_freq       :      integer    := (100e6/270e3) - 1 -- Operating frequency of display
    );
    port(
        CLK100MHZ, reset: in std_logic; -- 100MHZ clock and reset signal
        LCD_RW:           out std_logic; -- Read/write bit for LCD
        LCD_RS:           out std_logic; -- Register Select for LCD
        LCD_E:            out std_logic; -- Enable bit for the LCD
        data:             out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) -- Data being sent to LCD including setup bits. 
    );
end entity;

architecture arch of LCD is
 Type control is (RESET_1,RESET_2,RESET_3, FUNCTION_SET, DISPLAY_OFF1, DISPLAY_CLEAR, DISPLAY_ON1, ENTRY_MODE_SET, WRITE_T, RETURN_HOME,TOGGLE_E, HOLD);
 signal freq_div :std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
 signal clk270 : std_logic; -- LCD clock
 signal state, next_cmd: control; 

begin

-- Clock for the LCD frequency 
    process(CLK100MHZ, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            freq_div <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(CLK100MHZ) then
            if freq_div = LCD_freq then
                clk270 <= '1';
                freq_div <= (others => '0');
            else
                clk270 <= '0';
                freq_div <= freq_div + 1;
            end if; -- freq_div
        end if; -- reset
    end process; 
            
-- State diagram controlling display
    process(CLK100MHZ, reset)   
    begin
    if reset = '1' then
       LCD_E <= '1';
       LCD_RS <= '0';
       LCD_RW <= '0';
       data <= "00111000";
       state <= TOGGLE_E;
       next_cmd <= RESET_1;
    elsif rising_edge(CLK100MHZ) then
       if clk270 = '1' then 
            case state is  
                when RESET_1 =>
                    LCD_E <= '1';
                    LCD_RS <= '0';
                    LCD_RW <= '0';
                    data <= "00111000";
                    state <= TOGGLE_E;
                    next_cmd <= RESET_2;
                 when RESET_2 =>
                    LCD_E <= '1';
                    LCD_RS <= '0';
                    LCD_RW <= '0';
                    data <= "00111000";
                    state <= TOGGLE_E;
                    next_cmd <= RESET_3;
                when RESET_3 =>
                    LCD_E <= '1';
                    LCD_RS <= '0';
                    LCD_RW <= '0';
                    data <= "00111000";
                    state <= TOGGLE_E;
                    next_cmd <= FUNCTION_SET;
                --- Initilization steps done individually ---
                when FUNCTION_SET => -- sets the function for the display 
                    LCD_RS <= '0';
                    LCD_RW <= '0';
                    data <= "0011" & display_lines & font_type & "00";
                    LCD_E <= '1'; -- Enables function for display
                    state <= TOGGLE_E;
                    next_cmd <= DISPLAY_OFF1;
                when DISPLAY_OFF1 => -- Turns the display off 
                    LCD_E <= '1';
                    LCD_RS <= '0';
                    LCD_RW <= '0'; 
                    data <= "00001" & display_off & cursor & blink;
                    state <= TOGGLE_E;
                    next_cmd <= DISPLAY_CLEAR;
                when DISPLAY_CLEAR => -- Clears the display
                    LCD_E <= '1';
                    LCD_RS <= '0';
                    LCD_RW <= '0';
                    data <= "00000001";
                    state <= TOGGLE_E;
                    next_cmd <= DISPLAY_ON1;    
                when DISPLAY_ON1 => -- Turns on the display 
                    LCD_E <= '1';
                    LCD_RS <= '0';
                    LCD_RW <= '0';
                    data <= "00001" & display_on & cursor & blink;
                    state <= TOGGLE_E;
                    next_cmd <= ENTRY_MODE_SET;
                when ENTRY_MODE_SET =>   -- Sets the increment and shift 
                    LCD_E <= '1';
                    LCD_RS <= '0';
                    LCD_RW <= '0';
                    data <= "000001" & I_D & shift;
                    state <= TOGGLE_E;
                    next_cmd <= WRITE_T;
                when WRITE_T =>
                    LCD_RS <= '1';
                    LCD_RW <= '0';
                    LCD_E  <= '1';
                    data <= "01000101"; --Letter T 
                    state <= TOGGLE_E;
                    next_cmd <= RETURN_HOME;
                when RETURN_HOME =>
                    LCD_E  <= '1';
                    LCD_RS <= '0';
                    LCD_RW <= '0';
                    data <= "00000010";
                    state <= TOGGLE_E;
                    next_cmd <= WRITE_T;
                    
                    -- Toggles a falling edge for Enable. 
                when TOGGLE_E =>
                    LCD_E <= '1';
                    state <= HOLD;
                when HOLD =>
                    state <= next_cmd;
                end case;
         end if; -- clk270kHz
      end if; -- reset
    end process;
end arch;
```

The display is of the archetype *ST7066U*. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Does it simulate correctly?

Comment: It simulates correctly and the signals are sent, I suspect that there must be a timeframe that needs to be met if the data is to be displayed

Comment: If it simulated correctly, what debugging have you done in teh hardware? Do all the LCD interface signals look correct on a scope?

Comment: I've used Waveforms to observe the ports, the correct bits are being sent at the right time. The LCD however I suspect might be faulty, next step is to test with a similar display with a similar state machine given in the datasheet

Comment: I don't see where `E` is reset to '0'. Are you sure you looked at all signals?

Comment: I managed to change E to reset to 0 at the state "TOGGLE_E", still no signal. Regarding the signals, E and RS are operating as they should. I will try to check every signal once more to be sure

Comment: Managed to find the problem, data was not being acknowledged by the display which resulted with the data not being displayed